# iOS app is crashing after kill and relauch using Adobe xcframeworks

Tags: ios, swift, crash, xcframework, dynamic-frameworks

I have added adobe AEPCore.xcframework in my application and kept it as "Do not embed" in framework setting.

Screenshot:
[image]

When i kill and relaunch the application, It got **crashed** with following logs.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AEPAssurance.framework/AEPAssurance
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6EF49835-678A-4B35-913B-5D88E3433DA3/app_name.app/app_name

Reason: image not found
```

dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

```
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection

DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

When I changed the framework setting to "**Embed and Sign**" Then release build fails on Jenkins.

**Error:**
`No UUID for /var/folders/zc/jp3qpb057hgf99tct24j3ch1xk6rfy/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~RRv4h3/libAEPMobileServices_iOS.a(AEPMobileServices.o)`

Any Help will be appreciated. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by keeping the framework setting as **"Embed and Sign in"** and kept AEPMobileServices framework as "Do not Embed" because this framework is a static library and It should not be included in the code.

[image]

This resolves the crash from QA build and export error from the release build.